# Помогите понять решение

Tags: php, javascript

У меня есть код:

```
var foo = '123';
var bar = "<? $php = foo ?>;
```

Таким образом конечно не работает, помогите решить задачу, я уже все перепробовал.

Как вставить значение переменной из **js** в переменную **php** с помощью данного кода?
Ну потом просто значение из **php** я внесу в **`$_SESSION['data']`** чтобы значение не терялось при перезагрузки страницы а продолжало рости.

Comment: Понять и простить? Чтоб решить задачу, нужно услышать вопрос. Если вопроса нет, то ответ 42.

Comment: Так вопрос сойдёт ?

Comment: Из php при отдаче ответа на запрос клиента можно внести изменения в js. Из js в php можно передать данные только отправкой запроса на сервер.

Comment: JS работает на стороне клиента. Без отправки POST|GET-запроса в виде URL передать переменную из JS не получится. Смотрите в сторону AJAX или меняйте содержимое формы отправки.

Answer (score 1):

Если отвечать упрощенно, то указанным способом - никак (здесь "никак" - примерно как в школе объясняют, что делить на ноль нельзя - потом оказывается, что на самом деле можно, но это совсем другая история). Объясню почему:

PHP-скрипт выполняется на сервере во время загрузки страницы и результатом работы будет текст, который может содержать HTML, JS, CSS и любые другие текстовые данные. Только после этого начинает выполняться JS, который может выполняться после загрузки страницы, до момента когда страница перезагрузится. Таким образом можно передавать значения переменных из PHP в JS, но не наоборот.

Если все же нужно, чтобы JS делал какие то действия и на сервере и на загруженной странице, то необходимо добиться того, чтобы JS без перезагрузки страницы передавал данные на сервер (с помощью XMLHttpRequest или AJAX), получал ответ и обрабатывал его. Так же можно пробовать применять cookie, эти данные будет получать и сервер и клиент, но сервер их получит только при загрузке следующей страницы.